# Clean Coding Use Attributes from Subclasses in Superclass

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I want to get better in coding and writing clean code.
I have a super-class Document and sub-classes, e.g. DocA, DocB, DocC, etc.
Each sub-class Document has this individual attribute egg. path, number, etc.
I want to write a method in the super-class like printPath(). I figure out two ways to do it.

1. Overwrite the attributes of the super-class (DocA)
2. Pass the elements to the method (DocB)

```
class Document {
    String path;

    public String getPathA() {
        return path;
    }

    public String getPathB(String path) {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}

class DocumentA extends Document{
    String path = "pathA";

    DocumentA () {
        setPath(this.path);
    }
}

class DocumentB extends Document{
    String path = "pathB";

    public String getPathB(){
        return super.getPathB(path);
    }
}
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to do it? Or rather is one of these ways OK?

Comment: It's not clear from this code why inheritance is useful. Or what you're trying to do. Honestly, I'm finding it hard to follow what it's all for.

Comment: if the path variable is a constant in DocumentA and DocumentB, you can change Document to become an abstract class and create an abstract method 'getPath', then DocA and DocB just provide the implementation to return their constants. the printPath method will just invoke getPath

Comment: I'd not consider it to be a clean design or clean code if the super class has knowledge of concepts that only the subclasses know. If they only make sense in the subclasses, keep them there. If they make sense for all, pull them up and potentially override methods for specific behavior.

Comment: Why do you need subclasses at all? Based on what you've told us so far, those subclasses seem unnecessary. Instead, the `Document` class can have a `path` with getter/setter, and then a/b/c can be instances of the `Document` class. E.g. `Document docA = new Document("path/to/a");`

Answer (score 1):

1. `Document.getPathA()` and `Document.getPathB()` should not even exist in the first place, because Document should not have any knowledge of `DocumentA` or `DocumentB`.
2. If Document already has `path`, then it looks very much like bad design if DocumentA and DocumentB also have a variable `path`, presumably with the same functionality.

**How to improve:**

If ALL Documents have a path, always use that path and retrieve it via `myDocument.getPatch()`. If DocumentA has some special additional functionality, you could override the method like this:

```
class DocumentA extends Document { 
    @Override public String getPath() {
         return someSpecialPath;
    } 
}
```

If NOT ALL Documents have a path, but only some,

1. Either create a second intermediary class like `class DocumentWithPath extends Document` as parent class for all those Documents that need a path
2. or simply leave it to the base classes to implement when needed

Another situation:

- If MOST Documents have a path
- and they ALL have to provide a specialized implementation
- and that Document needs to know about the path,

you can write an abstract method:

```
abstract class Document { // 'abstract shows that this class itself cannot be instantiated, but its fully implemented children can
    abstract public String getPath();
    String toString() { 
        return "My Path is: " + getPath(); // this calls the abstract method, implemented by any instantiable subclass
    }
}

class DocumentA extends Document { 
    @Override public String getPath() {
         return someSpecialPath;
    } 
}
```

This FORCES all child classes (that can be instantiated) to implement `getPath()` in their own way.

**Edit:**
If you define `path` in the parent as *protected*:

```
class Document {
    protected File path;
}
```

then you can access `path` from all subclasses as if it was their own member variable.